# Reading and displaying data from Firebase on your web app

Tags: javascript, firebase

Trying to building a simple Firebase web app. I have the following:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.2.3/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.2.3/firebase-database.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      // Your web app's Firebase configuration
      var firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "secret",
        authDomain: "secret",
        databaseURL: "secret",
        projectId: "secret",
        storageBucket: "secret",
        messagingSenderId: "secret",
        appId: "secret"
      };
      firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

      var database = firebase.database().ref('blacklist');
      database.on("value", function(snapshot){
        console.log(snapshot.val());
      });

    </script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My firebase structure looks like this[image]

All I'm trying to do at the moment is print the data in the console. the console is blank, not an error or anything is being shown? Could you assist with showing the data. Im trying to show the fromId and toId for each one.

Comment: I assume `ref.on()` triggers at least one time initially? Do you also get nothing with `.once()`?

Comment: @Anthony, that also does not do anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As im only using this for development purposes, I found out that i need to set the permissions of the app to:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "true",
    ".write": "true"
  }
}
```

The above code I was using is correct and works as expected

Answer (score 0):

Something like this happened to me once but it was in and Android app. If I am seeing your full database structure, try adding an inner branch, any one of the ones inside blacklist like this and see if you get a "value" back

```
var database = firebase.database().ref('Li2.../' + 'blacklist');
```

To explain why I ask you to try this; in this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write it says

> Typical usage
>
> **value**:    Read and listen for changes to the entire contents of a path.

At the time I was trying this on Android it seemed that "**paths**" were not treated as "**values**" so if in a path there was no explicit data then it would not print to debug but it would print for those that had data. In the link I gave it says

> If there is no data, the snapshot will return false when you call
> exists() and null when you call val() on it.

I think this will help you find where the problem is.